# What are .cmd or .com files in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm new to Linux and saw files named "example.cmd" and "test.com".

How do I open these files? Also, what kind of files are these?

Comment: In Linux, filename extensions are not as important as on MS Windows. Do not rely on them much.

Comment: as in, they don't exist. People use the dotted notation for convenience only. The vast majority of the time anyhow (i.e: unless a particular app is coded in an odd way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As luke says, you should use the `file` utility to try to find out the truth; but my best guess is that these are actually Windows scripts/executables that have somehow found their way onto a linux system.

This means there might not be much point opening them.  Still, but you could just start by trying to run the command `less example.cmd` or `less test.com`, and if you just see garbage, try `hexdump`.  I don't know if that counts as "opening" in any useful sense, but at least you might find out something.

Comment: I would use `strings` on suspected binaries before using `less`. But use `file` first.

Comment: the "com" file is a ASCII text, what does that mean?

Comment: It depends on what the text is.  You should definately just open it up using less or your faviourite text editor and have a look.  It might be a script of some kind, if @file@ says "ASCII text" it might just be a document written by and for humans, but it might just be that it was doesn't know what kind of text it is.   By the way, what is the context, where is this file and how did you get it?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command on the files, e.g:

```
file test.com
```

and see if it gives you any useful information.

Comment: when I did that, it said "the file is an ascii text"

Comment: OK, you can go ahead and run `less test.com` to view the contents of the file as @Adrian Ratnapala suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Many cross-platform applications include both windows (.cmd) and unix/linux (.sh, etc) scripts, usually to start up an application.  A bit more information about where you saw them, what the actual names are, etc would be needed to determine exactly what you're looking at.

[.com files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) are a hold-over from the MS-DOS days.